# Can two temporary tables with the same name exist in separate queries

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering, if it is possible to have two temp tables with the same name in two separate queries without them conflicting when called upon later in the queries.

Query 1: Create Temp Table Tmp1 as ...

Query 2: Create Temp Table Tmp1 as ...

Query 1: Do something with Tmp1 ...

I am wondering if postgresql distinguishes between those two tables, maybe through addressing them as Query1.Tmp1 and Query2.Tmp1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each connection to the database gets its own special [temporary schema name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76661), and temp tables are created in that schema. So there will not be any conflict between concurrent queries from separate connections, even if the tables have the same names. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5237 for more info

The [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) for creating tables states:

> Temporary tables exist in a special schema, so a schema name cannot be given when creating a temporary table.