# Postgresql 8.4 a variable hold set of records returned from another function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am using postgresql 8.4 in backend

I have a postgres function say A() it can return a set of records (3 columns) like:

```
<A_id>::int,<A_ts_1>::timestamp,<A_ts_2>::timestamp
```

function A define like this(for example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
          RETURNS SETOF record AS
          $$
          DECLARE

            BEGIN
                RETURN QUERY SELECT DISTINCT ON (A.id) A.id, A.ts_1, A.ts_2 FROM tablea;

         END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
      SQL
```

function A has been called in another function B. In function B I need a variable to hold what returned from A() then do some query for example:

```
<variable> = select * from A();
a_id_array = ARRAY(select A_id from <variable>);
a_filtered_array =  ARRAY(select A_id from <variable> where A_ts_1 ><a_timestamp> and A_ts_2 < <a_timestamp>);
```

**So My question is what variable I should define to hold the set of records returned from A().**

I tried temp table which really not good for multi-session env, it blocks data insertion. [postgresql create temp table could block data insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479118/postgresql-create-temp-table-could-block-data-insertion/44479513#44479513)

I checked doc for views seems not meet my requirements, however I may wrong so if any of you could give me an idea on how to use view in this case and use view will block data insertion as well?

Thank all!

P.S.
I think the worse case is in function B() I call function A() twice for example:

```
a_id_array = ARRAY(select A_id from A());
a_filtered_array =  ARRAY(select A_id from A() where A_ts_1 ><a_timestamp> and A_ts_2 < <a_timestamp>);
```

**Then my question would slightly change, can I achive this case just using one function call to A()?**

Comment: Found this artical [https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions)  not sure this would help for not

Comment: This might help: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/store-multiple-rows-with-the-SELECT-INTO-statement-td5769258.html

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=1687cd8fbefac27b6b80e3387ea866ee

Comment: I tried your answer but I am not able to do a performance test. If returned setof record is quite large will this function becomes slow? Check the answer I wrote with **WITH query**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, found a way to replace using temp table and query returned set of record which is using **WITH query**.

```
      SELECT c.r_ids, c.a_r_ids into a_id_array, a_filtered_array FROM(
      WITH returned_r AS (SELECT * FROM a())
      SELECT * from (
      SELECT ARRAY( SELECT A_id from returned_r ) as r_ids ) as a
      CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT ARRAY(SELECT A_id FROM returned_r WHERE A_ts_1 is NOT NULL AND A_ts_2 IS NULL) as a_r_ids
      ) as b
      ) as c;
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't (yet, as of postgres 10) have table-valued variables backed by a tuplestore. So your best options are:

- Return a `REFCURSOR` and use it from the other function. Can be clumsy to work with as you cannot reuse the resultset easily or `FETCH` in a subquery. It's not always easy to generate a cursor resultset either, depending on how you're creating the results.
- Use temp tables with generated names so they don't collide. Lots of dynamic SQL involved here (`EXECUTE format(...)`) but it works.
- Avoid trying to pass result sets between functions